# How to wait for asynchronous task to end - Swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I need to read data from a Firebase database and insert the data inside a struct, on which I'll later do some operations. The issue that I'm facing right now is that, since Firebase manages these things in an async way, when I check inside the struct, it's often nil and not filled with data yet.

I know that using the value outside the async block as I'm actually doing is wrong and that callbacks can be used to solve my problem. I've read a bunch of examples online, but I can't figure out how to implement them in my code.

For the sake of simplicity, in the example below I download just one object from the database.

```
func fetchJSON(key: String) -> Void {
  var meal = Meal()
  let ref = rootRef.child(key)

  ref.observe(.value) { (snap: DataSnapshot) in   
      meal.firstMeal = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "first").value as! String
      meal.secondMeal = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "second").value as! String
      meal.thirdMeal = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "third").value as! String         
    }

  self.meals.append(meal)
}
```

And here's what the function call looks like:

```
fetchJSON(key: currentDate)
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Not sure I got you, but look up "swit completion handlers"

Comment: Here are [more than 700 related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+firebase+completion)

Answer (score 1):

For Firebase you may also find handy promises. I use the [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) library and it's working great.

You could do something like this:

```
fetchJSON(key: currentDate).done { meal in
    print(meal)
}

func fetchJSON(key: String) -> Promise<Meal> {
        let ref = rootRef.child(key)
        return Promise { seal in
            ref.observe(.value) { (snap: DataSnapshot) in
                guard let firstMeal = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "first").value as! String,
                      let secondMeal = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "second").value as! String,
                      let thirdMeal = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "third").value as! String {
                        let meal = Meal(firstMeal: firstMeal, 
                                        secondMeal: secondMeal, 
                                        thirdMeal: thirdMeal)
                            seal.fulfill(meal)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [completionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html), first declare [typealias](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html) in your class

```
typealias completion = (_ isFinished:Bool) -> Void
```

then add **completionHandler** to your function:

```
func fetchJSON(key: String, completionHandler: @escaping completion){
    var meal = Meal()
    let ref = rootRef.child(key)

    ref.observe(.value) { (snap: DataSnapshot) in
        meal.firstMeal = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "first").value as! String
        meal.secondMeal = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "second").value as! String
        meal.thirdMeal = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "third").value as! String
    }

    meals.append(meal)
    completionHandler(true)
}
```

then call your function like this way:

```
fetchJSON(key: currentDate, completionHandler: { (isFinished) in
    if isFinished {
        // do Somthing
    }
})
```

Comment: This won't work. The last two lines in `fetchJSON` must be **within** the `observe` closure.